# Compatibility of auto-pst-pdf with Overleaf-Latex

Tags: pstricks, overleaf, auto-pst-pdf

I have been trying various different things for quite a while now, but cannot manage to get the package `auto-pst-pdf` to cooperate with Overleaf-latex.

Additionally, `pstricks` gives many arrows: for example, when using the commands  `\psline` `\psaxes`, `\psGauss`, etc.

Is there a way to fix those problems?

Comment: @LianTzeLim not related at all to the current question, but isn't your disclaimer more like a disclosure (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115850/disclaimer-vs-disclosure)?

Comment: @Marijn Apologies, will use "Disclosure" next time.

Comment: _[Disclaimer/Disclosure: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf]_ Have you perhaps tried compiling with XeLaTeX? It supports pstricks, so you won't need `auto-pst-pdf`.

Comment: @LianTzeLim: XeLaTeX works in a lot of cases, but not in all!